# How do I run clang's static analyzer from tundra

Tags: clang-static-analyzer

We use tundra as our build system, and would like to run our builds through clang's static analyzer. The scan-build script that one uses to invoke clang's analyzer works by modifying the CC and CXX environment variables, but this approach doesn't work for tundra, since tundra sets up it's own environment explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of tundra2/scripts/tundra/tools/clang.lua, and call it clang-analyze.lua
2. Inside clang-analyze.lua, replace the CC, CXX, and LD commands with "ccc-analyzer", which is the clang-analyzer dummy compiler.

   ```
   env:set_many {
     ["CC"] = "ccc-analyzer",
     ["CXX"] = "ccc-analyzer",
     ["LD"] = "ccc-analyzer",
   }
   ```
3. Add a new build configuration to your project that uses the clang-analyze toolchain, like this:

   ```
   Configs = {
   {
       Name = "linux-analyze",
       SupportedHosts = "linux",
       Inherit = unix_common,
       Tools = { "clang-analyze" },
   },
   ```
4. Make sure that ccc-analyzer is accessible on your PATH
5. Run scan-build:

   ```
   scan-build --use-cc clang --use-c++ clang++ ./tundra2 --rebuild linux-analyze-debug-default`
   ```

   If your regular compiler is gcc, then you'd run scan-build like so:

   ```
   scan-build --use-cc gcc --use-c++ g++ ./tundra2 --rebuild linux-analyze-debug-default`
   ```

From there, you should be able to figure out how to integrate that into your CI system.